# Karma fails to run PhantomJS unit tests on AWS CodeBuild but works locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, phantomjs, karma-runner, aws-codebuild

I've got an AngularJS project I'm putting together. The app runs and executes normally. The tests run and execute ... locally. When I do the build on AWS CodeBuild, I get the following errors in my log:

```
[Container] 2017/01/17 21:54:36 [21:54:36] Starting 'karma:single-run'...
[Container] 2017/01/17 21:54:37 [32m17 01 2017 21:54:37.350:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
[Container] 2017/01/17 21:54:37 [32m17 01 2017 21:54:37.351:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
[Container] 2017/01/17 21:54:37 [32m17 01 2017 21:54:37.356:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser PhantomJS
[Container] 2017/01/17 21:55:37 [33m17 01 2017 21:55:37.417:WARN [launcher]: [39mPhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[Container] 2017/01/17 21:55:39 [33m17 01 2017 21:55:39.421:WARN [launcher]: [39mPhantomJS was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
[Container] 2017/01/17 21:55:41 [33m17 01 2017 21:55:41.424:WARN [launcher]: [39mPhantomJS was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.
```

I run the same Gulp task to execute the tests in both locations:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const path = require('path');

const gulp = require('gulp');
const karma = require('karma');

gulp.task('karma:single-run', karmaSingleRun);
gulp.task('karma:auto-run', karmaAutoRun);

function karmaFinishHandler(done) {
  return failCount => {
    done(failCount ? new Error(`Failed ${failCount} tests.`) : null);
  };
}

function karmaSingleRun(done) {
  const configFile = path.join(process.cwd(), 'conf', 'karma.conf.js');
  const karmaServer = new karma.Server({configFile}, karmaFinishHandler(done));
  karmaServer.start();
}

function karmaAutoRun(done) {
  const configFile = path.join(process.cwd(), 'conf', 'karma-auto.conf.js');
  const karmaServer = new karma.Server({configFile}, karmaFinishHandler(done));
  karmaServer.start();
}
```

and my karma.conf.js file is the same, too:

```
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');

module.exports = function (config) {
  const configuration = {
    basePath: '../',
    singleRun: true,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 20000,
    failOnEmptyTestSuite: false,
    autoWatch: true,
    logLevel: 'INFO',
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'test-reports'
    },
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],
    frameworks: [
      'jasmine',
      'jspm',
      'es6-shim'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      [conf.path.src('**/*.html')]: [
        'ng-html2js',
        'generic'
      ]
    },
    genericPreprocessor: {
      rules: [
        {
          process(content, file, done) {
            file.path = file.path.replace(/\.js$/, '.ts');
            done(content);
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {},
    jspm: {
      loadFiles: [
        conf.path.src('app/**/*.ts'),
        conf.path.src('**/*.html')
      ],
      config: 'jspm.config.js',
      browser: 'jspm.test.js'
    },
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-shim'),
      require('karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'),
      require('karma-jspm'),
      require('karma-generic-preprocessor'),
      require('karma-es6-shim')
    ]
  };

  config.set(configuration);
};
```

Any idea what's going on?

It bears mentioning that my local project is on Windows and the Node instances on Amazon is running on Ubuntu. Could it be some weird file system or versioning issue?

Comment: You probably need to use [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) callback, to find out, what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. The problem I'm having with the Gulp tools is that each one has a special, magic configuration file that works completely unlike the special, magic configuration file that every _other_ tool uses. Then you have the fact that how these tools are invoked and how their special, magic config files are laid out often will change from version to version ... It's very challenging for a newbie such as myself.

Comment: Any idea how to hook something into that onResourceError from the configuration above? There seem to be all sorts of components being used auto-magically like `karma-phantomjs-launcher`. Where is that even invoked?